# Re thread: How to load nav menu from an external file?

Tags: javascript, menu, external

Re thread How to load nav menu from an external file? (No Wamp, all code must be 'browser-side')
@ThomasJames

I tried Thomas James's solution (Javascript) from the top of the page.
Works beautifully in Firefox (Mac OSX). But not work in Chrome of Safari.
Note also Thomas's SolarWind.zip download also does not load in Chrome or Safari.

I thought we should be able to have Jacascript working in all browsers?

It seems that the other solutions ONLY work in Chrome and Opera.

Any thoughts? Thanks, Steve

Comment: Sorry if I posted this wrong? Cannot see how to respond to the original thread. Thanks, Steve

Comment: yeah I think you meant to respond to another thread but you just created a new one instead

Comment: I intentionally started a new thread. I could not see how to respond to the old one. i) The Answer section (of the thread) states only to provide answers, not comments or new questions. ii) I am not able to comment as I don't have enough 'reputation' privileges. So I can only see to start a new thread.